# When I set a UIButton's enabled property to NO, it automatically greys out the button (I'm using a picture for the button)

Tags: iphone, uibutton

How do I make it so it doesn't grey out?

Comment: Wouldn't you want it to be greyed out so that the user thinks they can't tap it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the same image for `UIControlStateDisabled` and `UIControlStateNormal` so the button does not generate the disabled state for you.

Comment: Eh, it doesn't look as good greyed out, and they will be able to tell they can't select it because the game isn't started.